# Remove any line beginning with specific string?

Tags: php, regex

I have the following string:

```
Q: What is your favorite color?
A: Red
Q: Who is your favorite actor?
A: George Clooney
```

I want to be left with:

```
A: Red
A: George Clooney
```

There are hundreds of possible questions (Q: xyz?), so I can't just str_replace each specific question.

Is there a function in PHP with regex that would allow me to delete all lines beginning with the following string: "Q: "

Comment: Is that an array of strings?

Comment: No there's no such function. You should combine function which reads lines from file (`fget` for example) and function which checks position of `Q:` in a string (`strpos`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this simple regex

```
 $string = preg_replace('/^Q:.+$/m', '', $string);
```

I used the `m` flag which should make `^` match the start of a line and `$` match the end, but some of it depends on what the input is like.

When testing above
[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a35a9d4ae9445249f74c36dd3b7be9a98e1d7b76)
it may leave the line endings.  So I modified it to this

```
 $string = preg_replace('/^Q:.+(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/m', '', $string);
```

Which should remove them.

[Sandobx](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/94b554cd3c2cf7051a2f128501691ccaf8d55756)

Which "duh" I just remembered that the `$` doesn't capture anything, so because it doesn't capture it, it wont be replace.

You could also break the data into lines first and test with match, like this

```
$string = 'Q: What is your favorite color?
A: Red
Q: Who is your favorite actor?
A: George Clooney';

$lines = preg_split("/[\r\n]+/",$string);

$fixed = [];

foreach($lines as $line) if(!preg_match('/^Q:/', $line)) $fixed[] = $line;


echo implode(PHP_EOL, $fixed);
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0f6e3205cd0bc178597510cea2c355b0d19b8652)

Comment: You're missing the colon here.

Comment: `.+` includes colon ;-)

Comment: This leaves empty lines where likes begin with Q

Comment: Yeah, I suppose if the input only starts with A: or Q:, that's fine but this would also match any other line starting with Q

Comment: bla bla .... lol  :)

Comment: Works perfectly. The other solutions do as well, but some of these strings have important text outside of the "Answer" lines, so this solution (which only removes the Q lines) does the trick.

Comment: @jm92 I have updated my answer below

Answer (score 3):

Id use [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) then [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php), for example:

```
<?php
$str = 'Q: What is your favorite color?
A: Red
Q: Who is your favorite actor?
A: George Clooney';

$array = explode(PHP_EOL, $str);

// get answers
$answers = array_filter($array, function ($value) {
    return substr($value, 0, 3) === 'A: ';
});

print_r($answers);
```

https://3v4l.org/6UKLZ

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [1] => A: Red
    [3] => A: George Clooney
)
```

And [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) it back for desired result:

https://3v4l.org/Esj98

```
A: Red
A: George Clooney
```

Comment: upvote +1  for not using regex

Comment: good answer but I would have used `return 0 === strpos($value,'A:');`  It should be faster then substr.  By using `0` we know it was the start of the string :-), so we can still be sure if there is a Q: in the middle it wont remove that.

Comment: I guess the performance is marginal, over 1m iterations, `strpos 1.0296 seconds` and `substr 1.0770 seconds` .. lol

Comment: Your right, can be done either way, I just picked substr as it was the first that popped into my head.

Answer (score 2):

You can use preg_match_all and capture all answers.

```
preg_match_all("/^A:.*$/m", $str, $m);
Echo implode(PHP_EOL, $m[0]);
```

The pattern

```
/^A: //must start with A:
.*   // Then anything
$    // to end of line
/m   // and make it multilined
```

https://3v4l.org/LPB25

---

If any of the answers are multilined, as in they have a line break you can use this code to get both lines.
The other answers will only capture single line answers.
This finds the next question and stops there

```
$str = "Q: What is your favorite color?
A: Red.
As in the color of a rose.
Q: Who is your favorite actor?
A: George Clooney";
preg_match_all("/(A:.*?).Q: /ms", $str . "\nQ: ", $m);
Echo implode(PHP_EOL, $m[1]);
```

I add a "extra question" with `$str . "\nQ: "`

This outputs

```
A: Red.
As in the color of a rose.
A: George Clooney
```

https://3v4l.org/UCArm